# JS Module : Difference between directly returning a function in an object and returning a function in an object returning a function

Tags: javascript

It's redundant but I am learning JS and I want to know how it really works.

1. Returning a function directly from a module

```
let func1 = function () {
    let test = function () {
        console.log("1");
    }
    return {
        getTest : test
    }
}
```

2. Returning a function by using a function

```
let func1 = function () {
    let test = function () {
        console.log("1");
    }
    return {
        getTest : function () {
            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: only difference is in second version to call test, you need to do `func1().getTest()()` whereas in first one you need to do `func1().getTest()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the `getTest` property of your object points to a function, so calling it this way:

```
func1().getTest()
```

Should result in logging 1.

In the second case, `getTest` returns a function which returns another function, so you'd have to also call the result in order to get `1`, this way:

```
func1().getTest()();
```

Calling just `getTest` will return your function object, rather than calling it.